# Android does not autocomplete

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio, and suddenly the import doesn't work today As you can see in the photo, just hitting Edi automatically completes the EditText, but now it doesn't autocomplete, and even if you use EditText and press alt + Enter, the import doesn't work.
Of course it is possible to import android.widget.EditText, but this method is very inefficient. What should I do? Help
[image]

[image]

Comment: File > Invalidate Catches / Restart

Comment: There's been several complaints on SO pointing out that AS 4.1(.1?) can't autocomplete (in, among others, Kotlin, Java, and Flutter, which is actually Dart?), that it spawns a ton of unnecessary OpenJDK processes, and just that it's showing a lot of weird behavior. Try rolling back a version for the time being; try the last version before 4.1 and see if that helps. If it does, stick to that version and try your luck with 4.1+ after Google pushes more updates to fix these bugs